# How does sleekxmpp components work?

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd

This may sound dumb but I followed this tutorial:

https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki/Creating-a-SleekXMPP-Plugin

and here's the component at the end that uses the XEP-0077 plugin that was created:

```
import sleekxmpp.componentxmpp

class Example(sleekxmpp.componentxmpp.ComponentXMPP):

    def __init__(self, jid, password):
        sleekxmpp.componentxmpp.ComponentXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password, 'localhost', 8888)

        self.registerPlugin('xep_0030')
        self.registerPlugin('xep_0077')
        self.plugin['xep_0077'].setForm('username', 'password')

        self.add_event_handler("registered_user", self.reg)
        self.add_event_handler("unregistered_user", self.unreg)

    def reg(self, iq):
        msg = "Welcome! %s" % iq['register']['username']
        self.sendMessage(iq['from'], msg, mfrom=self.fulljid)

    def unreg(self, iq):
        msg = "Bye! %s" % iq['register']['username']
        self.sendMessage(iq['from'], msg, mfrom=self.fulljid)
```

But I don't know how to use it, also I can't find any sleekxmpp documentation how to use this component. What I'm trying to accomplish here is to be able to register/unregister users on an xmpp server from python.

Answer (score 1):

Check out

http://louizatakk.fedorapeople.org/sleekxmpp-1.0-Beta2-0/examples/config_component.py

It will answer all of your questions. If not, post a comment with with the follow-up questions below.